# In Sublime Text, for syntax-specific preferences, how do you enable increase/decrease font size with CTRL+Mousewheel

Tags: fonts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, zoom, mouse-wheel

I am normally able to use CTRL+MouseWheel to increase and decrease the font size in Sublime Text (I am using Sublime Text 3).  This behavior appears to be on by default.

When I am in an editor window for SCALA code, this feature is somehow turned off!

I have tried editing the syntax-specific scala preference file, the default user file, the user preference file, the mouse behavior file, etc. to no avail.

Can anyone help me in allowing/restoring the CTRL+scrollwheel text zoom functionality for SCALA code in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. It seems that if you specify `font-size` in your syntax-specific settings, you can't change it as you would normally do with Ctrl + scrollwheel. If you remove `font-size` it should work. Hope this helps.